# count the binary gap

Tags: java, binary

I want to write a code that counts the binary gap of any given integers in java.

Comment: I assume you want an *integer* and not any *number*. Also - are you considering only integers that fit the primitive `int`?

Comment: yeah , that's integers !

Comment: binary gap in simple word is the number of zeros that are surrounded by 1 , for example 1001 has 2 binary gap .

Comment: What's the binary gap of `100101`?

Comment: *"any ideas?"* - My idea is that you should try writing the code yourself, and ask questions if you run into difficulties.

Comment: If I had any ideas how to start I would not asked for some help !

Comment: You could use [`Integer#toBinaryString` to transform your int into a binary string - you then only have to count the adjacent 0s](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#toBinaryString%28int%29).

Comment: but the zeros should be surrounded by 1

Comment: You can simply start from the 1st 1 found in the string and discard the preceding 0s.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with giving an answer to this question is

- You won't learn anything
- You can't use the answer for homework if you can't explain what you have done.

.

```
long l = 0b100101L;
String betweenOnes = Long.toBinaryString(l >> Long.numberOfTrailingZeros(l))
int zeros = Collections.max(Arrays.asList(betweenOnes).split("1+"))).length();
System.out.println(zeros);
```

prints

```
2
```

Comment: I know this is old, but the answer above is not only slow (operation on strings), its also wrong. This will print 3 for 0b1001000L.

Comment: @user1515791 How do you determine that the number is 0x1001000L and not 0x01001000L ?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you mean, maybe i'm missing something, but your solution returns 3 for 328, which should be 2 (101001000). A binary gap should start and end with 1

Comment: @user1515791 I see what you are saying, it's been a while since I wrote this.

Comment: check out this thread for similar discussion - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52731240/binary-gap-program-in-java